# Divide results of two SOQL queries

Tags: sql, salesforce, soql

I have two SOQL queries that access data from Salesforce that I want to divide. On their own each query works, and I want to divide their results by one another, but I am unsure how.

This is what I have tried:

```
select
(select count(success__c) from Account where success__c='yes'
and success__c>'30' and success__c<'37')
/
(select count(success__c) from Account where success__c='no')
As result
```

My SQL and SOQL experience is limited, so any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt the top one works, as you seem to be expecting `'yes'` to be between `'30'` and `'37'` (depending on the backing text encoding, one of those will be true, but not both).  That, and you're searching for a range of values on the same column you want exactly _one_ value.  It seems likely you have one or more typos in this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly in SOQL, you'll need to run both queries and do the division in whatever code is making these queries.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Annoying that it can't do that.

Comment: But subqueries are possible at least - at minimum you could do it in one query as two columns.  Why doesn't SOQL allow the division?